# how to" fix run error in flutter "? what i can do for it

Tags: flutter

"PS C:\Users\sushant dhore\Desktop\longin> flutter run
CreateProcessW failed 193

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Failed to send crash report due to a network error: SocketException: OS Error: The remote computer
refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225, address = clients2.google.com, port = 65047
\CreateProcessW failed 193

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.                                                                         |CreateProcessW failed 193                                                                               Crash report written to C:\Users\sushant dhore\Desktop\longin\flutter_03.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

Comment: When you run `flutter doctor`, does it indicate that you are missing any dependencies or that anything else is wrong? [`flutter doctor` docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor)

Comment: flutter doctor docs
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.950], locale en-IN)
\CreateProcessW failed 193

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.                                                                                        -CreateProcessW failed 193

Comment: It looks like it may be related to having spaces in the path [issue-18938](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18938). Some workarounds are suggested in that issue link. If your issue is not a dulicate, you could check the `flutter_03.log` file and post an issue to the flutter repo as the error message suggests.

Comment: yes  issue-18938 like this  Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly. Sending crash report to Google. Crash report sent (report ID: 78a0358525a922d3) \CreateProcessW failed 193 #39563
what should i do

Comment: I would attempt a few of the workarounds you find described in the GitHub issue to see if they can fix your problem, and then I would add your specific crash details from your log file to /issues in the Flutter repo.